# Hi guys, i have one column as "Input" and their data as A,B,B,C,D,D,D,E (8 records totally).Final output should be A1,B2,C1,D3,E1(using informatica)

Tags: informatica

In Informatica using which transformation we can get this problem to be solved

I tried introducing count column in aggregate transformation but output is like 2columns A 1,B 2,C 1,D 3,E 1...i need the output to be in 1 column alone

Answer (score 1):

After the Aggregator, you can add an Expression transformation. In this transformation you convert the count into a string and concatenate it with the first field.